# Convert integer array to string at javascript

Tags: javascript, utf-8

Here is php code:

```
$arr=array(228,184,173,230,150,135,99,104,105,110,101,115,101);
$str='';
foreach ($arr as $i){
    $str.=chr($i);
}
print $str;
```

the output is: `中文chinese`

Here is javascript code:

```
var arr=[228,184,173,230,150,135,99,104,105,110,101,115,101];
var str='';
for (i in arr){
    str+=String.fromCharCode(arr[i]);
}
console.log(str);
```

the output is: `ä¸­æchinese`

So how should I process the array at javascript?

Comment: When I run the PHP code, I get the output `ä¸­æ–‡chinese`. Is there anything special about your PHP configuration?

Comment: I get the same exact output as @Stegrex

Comment: @Stegrex Maybe it is the problem of locale setting. you could try to cancel the comment `zh_CN.XXX` at `/etc/locale.gen`

Comment: I am not sure how it works out in your PHP code. But for javascript the correct array is [20013,25991,99,104,105,110,101,115,101]

Comment: @Stegrex: you are viewing it in ASCII. Interpret it as UTF-8.

Comment: @Stegrex, @ 0DEFACED, add this line before the print: `header('Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8')`. Open it with a proper browser.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

JavaScript strings consist of [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) code units, yet the numbers in your array are the bytes of a [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) string. Here is one way to convert the string, which uses the [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) function:

```
var i, str = '';

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    str += '%' + ('0' + arr[i].toString(16)).slice(-2);
}
str = decodeURIComponent(str);
```

Performing the UTF-8 to UTF-16 conversion in the conventional way is likely to be more efficient but would require more code.

Comment: @PleaseStand, What do you mean by "conversion in the conventional way"? What "conventional way" are you referring to?

Comment: Using your method I got a `URIError: URI malformed`

Answer (score 6):

```
var arry = [3,5,7,9];
console.log(arry.map(String))
```

the result will be `['3','5','7','9']`

```
var arry = ['3','5','7','9']
console.log(arry.map(Number))
```

the result will be `[3,5,7,9]`

Answer (score 3):

Another solution without `decodeURIComponent` for characters up to 3 bytes (U+FFFF).
The function presumes the string is valid UTF-8, not much error checking...

```
function atos(arr) {
    for (var i=0, l=arr.length, s='', c; c = arr[i++];)
        s += String.fromCharCode(
            c > 0xdf && c < 0xf0 && i < l-1
                ? (c & 0xf) << 12 | (arr[i++] & 0x3f) << 6 | arr[i++] & 0x3f
            : c > 0x7f && i < l
                ? (c & 0x1f) << 6 | arr[i++] & 0x3f
            : c
        );

    return s
}
```

Comment: I tested this with Chinese, Russian, Hebrew and English, and it works. The code is not very readable, but it's the right approach.

Answer (score 3):

Seems the best way these days is the following:

```
function bufferToString(arr){
    return arr.map(function(i){return String.fromCharCode(i)}).join("")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Chinese charset has a different encoding in which one char is more than one byte long. When you do this

```
for (i in arr){
    str+=String.fromCharCode(arr[i]);
}
```

You are converting each byte to a char(actually string) and adding it to a string str.
What you need to do is, pack the bytes together.

I changed your array to this and it worked for me:

```
var arr=[20013,25991,99,104,105,110,101,115,101];
```

I got these codes from [here](https://www.martineve.com/2007/05/23/string-fromcharcode-encoder/).

you can also take a look at [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/pack-and-unpack-bytes-to-strings) for packing bytes to a string.